# Return JSON string from Play Framework controller

Tags: java, json, ajax, playframework

I am making an ajax POST request from the client. My Play Framework controller makes a request to a cross domain server which returns JSON. I then want to forward this JSON to the client. When I call `Promise<JsonNode>.toString()`, It appears I receive a memory address. How can I get the actual JSON back to the client?

```
    public static Result addVenue() {

      final Map<String, String[]> values = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
      String queryString = values.get("venueName")[0]  + ",+" + values.get("venueAddress")[0] + ",+" + values.get("venueCity")[0] + ",+" + values.get("venueState")[0] + "+" + values.get("venueZip")[0];
      String queryURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" + queryString + "&key=" + "AIzaSyD1xSgKUnEZ_tM7qzcEAeM-SJBxPFhIpaU";
      queryURL = queryURL.replaceAll(" ", "+");

      Promise<JsonNode> jsonPromise = WS.url(queryURL).get().map(
              new Function<WSResponse, JsonNode>() {
                  public JsonNode apply(WSResponse response) {
                      JsonNode json = response.asJson();
                      return json;
                  }
              }
      );

      response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response().setHeader("Allow", "*");
      response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
      response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent");
      return ok(jsonPromise.toString());
}
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? Answer is right there.  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync

Comment: @Ryan yes I did, however, the documentation refers to returning the body of a request as son, not getting a new response from an external web service.

Comment: Just curious, why was this -1?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because the answer is in the documentation. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaWS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a promise of result instead:

```
public static Promise<Result> addVenue() {
    return WS.url(URL).get().map((response) -> {
        return ok(response.asJson());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to figure it out last night finally. My code is a little different. I will post it below.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to return the JSON using the following code. My implementation is a little different than another answer provided. I will provide it just in case the other one doesn't work for some people.

```
 final Promise<Result> resultPromise = WS.url(queryURL).get().map(
            new Function<WSResponse, Result>() {
                public Result apply(WSResponse response) {
                    Logger.info(response.asJson().toString());
                    return ok(response.asJson().toString());
                }
            }
 );
 return resultPromise;
```

Comment: This is the same as above, but for Java 7 :)
Note that you don't need to use ".toString()" to send Json in the response